# CSS line-height issue across browsers

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, css

I have some button controls with CSS line-height: 18px.  Some are input controls type="button", and others are anchors stylized to appear as buttons like the input controls.  In FF3.6.12/IE8 they are displaying the same height, but in IE7, the anchors are shorter in height.  How do I get them to display correctly in IE7?

Comment: I'll take a look if you can provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case that accurately reproduces your problem.

Comment: jsFiddle - for the HTML window:<div class="Footer">
<input id="SaveButton" type="button" value="Save">
<input id="SubmitButton" type="button" value="Submit">
<a class="Button" href="/">Reset</a>
</div>

Comment: CSS window:
.Footer
{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px;
    border-top:1px solid #557AB5;
    font-style:italic;
}

.Footer input[type=button],
.Footer input[type=submit],
.Footer .Button
{
    float:right;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
}

Comment: input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
.Button
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEFF;
    border: 1px solid #414649;
    color: #002570;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #DCECF6;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

Comment: input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
.Button:hover
{
    border: 2px solid #414649;
    padding:2px 6px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0.0px #DCECF6;
}
input[type="button"]:disabled,
input[type="submit"]:disabled,
.Button:disabled
{
    background-color:#F4F4F4;
    color:#87908E;
    border: 2px solid #BCC0C2;
    cursor:auto;
    padding:2px 6px;
}

Comment: You will see the described behavior therein.

Comment: @KingCobra42: Can't you paste it in there yourself? Click the "Save" button once you've done so. The link you need to give me will be in your address bar. Test it in IE7 to make sure the demo has the same problem.

Comment: Oh, I did not know about the link being in the address bar to send you.  I'll get it for you.

Comment: Here you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/DnGvF/

Comment: I have used jsfiddle in the past just to test code, but had not saved anything there before.

Comment: I'll be leaving the office shortly, but will check for you feedback in the morning.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I took your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DnGvF/

and added just this CSS at the end: http://jsfiddle.net/gRF9g/

```
/* ie7 fixes */
.Footer input[type=button],
.Footer input[type=submit]
{
    overflow: visible;
    *height: 24px;
    *line-height: 15px
}
```

Some explanation of what's going on there:

- There's a known bug in IE7 that `overflow: visible` fixes, related to the width of the button. Try looking at my demo in IE7 with and without it.
- I'm using the [Star property hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack) to provide change the `height` and `line-height` for only IE7 and lower. You can tweak the numbers I picked if you need to.
- That hack is invalid CSS, but there's no problem using it. It's never going to come back and bite you - it's a "safe hack". Nevertheless, if you require 100% valid CSS, there are alternatives.

It now looks consistent between IE7 and the later versions.

Yes, this is a little kludgy, but at least it's all together in the CSS in one place, with a clear comment.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if IE7 is the only problem, I'd just go with a hack and bump up the line-height:

```
*+html .button { line-height:24px }
```

If you use something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), you could do away with the hack and use:

```
.ie7 .button { line-height:24px }
```

Of course, the other alternative is to actually track down why IE7 is behaving the way it is, and rewrite your CSS accordingly, but without any posted code, I can't help you with that.

**EDIT:** Forgot about this method of targeting just IE7:

```
<!--[if IE7]><style type="text/css">.button{line-height:24px}</style><![endif]-->
```

Comment: input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
.Button 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEFF;
    border: 1px solid #414649;
    color: #002570;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #DCECF6;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

Comment: <input id="SaveButton" class="Button" type="button" value="Save">
<input id="SubmitButton" class="Button" type="button" data-orderno="426" value="Submit">
<a class="Button" href="/OrderSummary/Display/426">Reset</a>

Comment: Well, nothing looks out of place there, but I think you took me a little too literally. It would take looking over all the CSS that's run on that page, probably even the HTML that's used in constructing the button, and even then, there might not be a solution to be had. If bumping up the line-height just for IE7 works, then go with that. It's not worth the time or trouble to try to align your code with IE7's buggy rendering engine.

Comment: I tried bumping up the value to 24 on that property, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: What is interesting is that the CSS for those controls is identical when viewing it in Firebug while in FF.  A buggy rendering engine - just what we need, another one of those!

Comment: Unfortunately it is requirement of the project to support IE7.

Comment: Haha, well, it's not technically *another* one of those. It's the same one: Trident. The same bloody buggy rendering engine Microsoft has been trying to polish since IE3. IE9 does pretty well now, but I still think it's only a matter of time before we'll be doing hacks for that too.

Comment: There's a difference between support and pixel-parity. If you've agreed to pixel-parity, I'm sorry, because your life is going to be a never-ending hell. The button works, still, I take it? It's just not the same height?

Comment: Yes, they work.  Just ugly being different heights.  We haven't actually agreed to pixel-parity, so we're not locked in on that count.

Comment: I know it sounds retarded, but have you thought about taking it the other way? Instead of trying to make the anchors higher, bring the line-height down on the buttons (inputs, that is) in IE7.

Comment: That is kludgy, since it can only be applied to IE7, but I guess that may be the best answer.

Comment: But I guess anything to solve this is going to be inherently kludgy. No insult intended.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in IEs have additional padding/borders/whatever - they do not style well as in other browsers.

Comment: Even if there is CSS that should theoretically override the default styling for them for IE7?

Comment: Theoretically you can try to experiment with `padding-top/bottom; line-height` of button or anchor.

Comment: Well, I set the padding, which was not set, for my Button class (applied to anchors), and I can see in Firebug while in FF that it is now the same for both anchors and inputs.  However, it does not fix the problem in IE7.